Autodesk Tandem Viewer (React)
I am new to APS and Javascript but I wanted to create a proof of concept using Autodesk Tandem. I am trying to get the Tandem-Viewer-React-2Legged to work but I seem to be unable to do so.
I have followed the instructions, starting server.ts using debugger in node.js. The first error is due to importing of ES modules so I added "type": "module" which fix the issue but the second error is due to Uncaught TypeError TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
If I change server.ts to server.mjs, the server works but frontend would have the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://tandem.autodesk.com/api/v1/groups' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
Please advice.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I assume you're referring to this sample. Do you start server directly using Node.js or do you run it through VS Code? I use VS Code as my dev environment so while developing I run it through it (actually I have one window for server and other window for client). It would be possible to run it using Node.js but you would need to transpile .ts to .js first.
You may want to checkout Test Bed sample which uses vanilla JavaScript.

I run the code through VS.Code. Firstly, I open the server folder in terminal and run npm install then I select server.ts and press F5 which led to a prompt asking for me to select the configuration which I then select node.js.
These are the steps leading to the issue.

I see. Here is how I use it. Open tandem-viewer-react-2legged/server in one window and then simply run it using Run - Start Debugging. Note it will automatically load env variables from .env file. Then I open tandem-viewer-react-2legged/client in second window and use npm run dev to start client.

Hmm. I am not really sure what's the issue either. It probably due to how I run it, I will try to transpile .ts to .js to see if it works later.
Meanwhile, I tried the Test Bed Sample which you suggested and encounter the following issue when I login, do you know what could have been the cause?
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "'token' response type is not supported."
}

Hard to say. Can you drop me message via e-mail, pls? We can try to resolve this via call.
